# How to reuse asp.net core dll in Xamarin Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi i'm try to build cross-platform project use Xamarin-Forms. I have build asp.net MVC project and i want re-use dll from my existing asp.net project in my Xamarin-Forms Project. Is there way how to do that?

I have try adding new reference into my Xamarin Project but always give me error when i try to build solution, example like this :

> Error Exception while loading assemblies:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly
>   'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for
>   Android profile?

Can i just copy-paste dll from asp.net project to my xamarin project?

Thanks.

Comment: Xamarin and ASP.NET are not compatible together. The best way to share a project library is to make a .NET Standard library, which will be able to target both. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

https://blog.xamarin.com/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/

Comment: @tura08, thanks for reply, is there way to convert asp.net xxxx.dll into .NET standart library?

Comment: Not really, but there is an API analyzer that will tell you how compatible your current dll is with .net standard https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer, then you can port the parts that aren't.